# separate some different data from a main array and merge each one to the main array again

Tags: php, arrays

the following array is an example of what I have(please visit the url):

https://codepen.io/oghab98/pen/LeajRR

Now I want to separate arrays with same id in `cart_details` key then merge theme with `its parent array`.

one want to do this because I should have each payments with same id to be in cart_details

if there is any questions or you didn't understand my code please ask it in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use the *classic* `foreach` loop.

```
$array = [
  'id' => 2,
  'title' => 'world',
  'meta' => 25,
  'key' => 'text',
  'sub_arr' => [
      [
          'id' => 55
      ],
      [
          'id' => 55
      ],
      [
          'id' => 224
      ]
  ]
];

//Init $result array. Initially, this will be an associative array. using the `sub_arr` `id` as the key.
$result = array();

//Loop $array[ "sub_arr" ]
foreach ( $array[ "sub_arr" ] as $arr ) {

    //Check if $result[ $arr["id"] ] exist. eg: $result[55]
    if ( !isset( $result[ $arr["id"] ] ) ) {

        //Does not exist. So assign the the $array to $result[55]
        $result[ $arr["id"] ] = $array;

        //Overide the value of $result[55][""sub_arr""]
        $result[ $arr["id"] ][ "sub_arr" ] = [ $arr ];
    } else {

        //Already exist. So just push the new $arr to $result[55][""sub_arr""]
        $result[ $arr["id"] ][ "sub_arr" ][] = $arr;
    }
}

//Return all the values of an array. This will make the array from associative to basic numerical array
$result = array_values( $result );
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => world
            [meta] => 25
            [key] => text
            [sub_arr] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 55
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 55
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => world
            [meta] => 25
            [key] => text
            [sub_arr] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 224
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: thank you.It's great.  but I'm beginner can you explain more about the code?

Comment: Sure. Ill put some comments in a bit.

Comment: I added some comments. Please let me know if you have questions

Comment: I need your help again. I changed the question. Can you give me an answer now?

Comment: Is the new question related to the old one? If it is not related, it is advisable for you to open a new question post instead

Comment: It's related to the old one.

Comment: No, this is a different problem. The `array` is even different. You can't edit the question post this way. Post here is SO is being used as a reference on future developers that have the same problem. If you edit the problem, the question is now different on the accepted answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163644/discussion-between-mahdi98-and-eddie).